# WCF: Should all datacontracts use the same namespace?

Tags: apache-flex, wcf, wsdl

I have several service contracts exposed over WCF, which use multiple datacontracts. The service is to be consumed by Adobe Flex. I've run into many problems getting Flex to consume the WSDL produced by the server. I used the procedure outlined [here](http://weblogs.asp.net/pglavich/archive/2010/03/16/making-wcf-output-a-single-wsdl-file-for-interop-purposes.aspx) to squeeze the WSDL into a single file (I used FlatWsdl and not WcfExtras, if it matters).

Now I'm getting a bunch of errors when using VS2010's own wsdl.exe tool to extract my metadata. Specifically, I'm getting the following errors:

```
1) Schema validation warning: Schema item 'complexType' named 
   'ArrayOfKeyValueOfSomeKeySomeValuep1alXzIb' from namespace 
   'http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays' is invalid. 
   Namespace 'http://My/Wcf/Namespace' is not available to be referenced
   in this schema.

2) Schema validation warning: Schema item 'complexType' named 'MyComplexType'
   from namespace 'http://My/Wcf/Namespace' is invalid. Namespace 
   'http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/My.Real.Namespace' is not available
   to be referenced in this schema.
```

Now, the Dictionary ("ArrayOfKeyValueOf...") type is apparently defined in an external schema, which is not imported by my WSDL. Please note that SomeKey and SomeValue have a datacontract namespace of My/Wcf/Namespace.

As for MyComplexType, the weird thing is that if I change its Datacontract-namespace to the same namespace used by my services, servers, and bindings, then error (2) goes away. I can't figure out why.

What I'm asking boils down to two questions:

1) How can I add an import directive of an external schema to my WSDL? I saw some solutions on-line that suggested writing a wrapper class around the containers. This is something I would really like to avoid.

2) Do I really have to put all my datacontracts into a single namespace? I don't have any technical objection to doing it, but it's going to be very cumbersome to modify the namespace of all datacontracts. Perhaps there's an automated way of achieving this?

TIA!

Comment: This won't answer your question, but if these services are only designed for consumption with Adobe Flex, I would strongly recommend switching from WebServices and moving to an AMF protocol with WebORB or FlourineFX.  Beyond that, have you used a tool like ServiceCapture to figure out what data is being sent back and forth?  What is youf Flex code for consuming the services?

Comment: I suppose that's one way to go, but it will be quite a bit of a re-design. You see, the services were originally meant to be consumed with C#, and only recently did we make the move to Flex. Also, we would like to expose our services in a standard manner to allow third-party developers to interact with them.

Comment: I haven't used a capturing tool. What do you expect to see there? I know what the WSDL looks like, and wsdl.exe claims it's broken. Do you think any further insight can be gained from sniffing the wire? As for how we consume the services in flex: we wanted to use Flex's "webservice introspection" ability. In other words - we want to consume the services as plain webservices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So just in case anyone else runs into the same problem with accessing a WCF (BasicHttpBinding) server from a Flex client:

1) No, all DataContracts need not be in the same namespace (but all ServiceContracts, service implementations, and bindings *do* have to be in the same namespace!).

2) The crux of the problem is that Flex expects each xsd:schema to have an "xsd:import namespace" for all the namespaces it references. This import should be of the form:

```
<xsd:import namespace="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/SomeNamespace" />
```

There doesn't seem to be a way to do this with WCF, since it automatically adds an auto-generated schemaLocation attribute to this tag, which makes Flex try to fetch this schemaLocation. The only workaround appears to be manually manipulating the WSDL at the XML level (e.g. by exposing a REST endpoint for retrieving the metadata).

Thanks to Yaron Naveh in the MSDN WCF forums for his help. The discussion can be found at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wcf/thread/b9429e30-e4d5-454f-9fbd-bae39990ff33.

Comment: We ran into a similar problem when trying to use a WCF SOAP service from Flex. Could you clarify your answer a little bit? Are you saying that the mere presence of the `schemaLocation` attribute on those imports is what's causing Flex to break? How would it find the referenced schemas without it?

Comment: @Matti: indeed, the schemaLocation added by WCF breaks Flex. The issue is that everything is already embedded inside the WSDL (you must use a "flat WSDL"), so that there is no need to refer to any external schema. Eventually we wrote a small program to modify the WSDL for us (modify the imports).

Comment: @Matti: to clarify on the "modify the imports" above: what we do is for each schema in the `<wsdl:types>` node, we add an import for all other schemas as well as `http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/`, `http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays`, and `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System`. For each System schema (i.e. a schema containing `http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System`) we add an import of `http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization`.

Comment: Ah, so the problem is that 1) Flex doesn't like schemas imported from external sources and 2) the generated referenced XSD schemas don't properly import everything they reference? I guess that shouldn't be too hard to fix. Thanks!